# Creating bash script files to create S3 bucket

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I wrote these commands to create s3 bucket:

```
bucketname=test1234
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*** AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*** REGION=us-east-1 aws s3 mb "s3://$bucketname"
```

This successfully creates a bucket. but when I copy this in a file, passing the bucket name as an argument and run the script file I get an error:

```
Script in the file:
bucketname=$1
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*** AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*** REGION=us-east-1 aws s3 mb "s3://$bucketname"
```

Bash file : `createbucket.txt`
Command used: `./createbucket.txt buckettest1234`

```
    Error:

         Parameter validation failed:ettest1234
    ": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"
```

It even takes out the first 4 letters for some reason.

Comment: Use quotes around variables ? Also u might have to escape specials chars with \

Comment: I'd also put single quotes around the secrets and put each variable on its own line--it could be that bash is trying to interpret something inside of them.
Like: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='***'` one one line and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='***'` on another and `REGION='us-east-1'` on another and `aws s3 mb "s3://$bucketname"` on the last line.

Comment: Why assign `bucketname=$1`? Just use `aws s3 mb "s3://$1"`

Comment: Thank you @MatrixManAtYrService and Mike Q your recommendations worked. Could you please add your comment as an answer so that I can up vote it?  John I was just trying something out and forgot it is the same. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're getting indicates that something is happening to the bucket name before it is making it to the `aws` command.  You're expecting `buckettest1234` but you're getting something like `ettest1234`.

To make it easier to see why this is happening, try wrapping your secrets in single quotes, your variable references in double quotes, and initializing your variables on their own lines, and printing the intermediate value, like so:

createbucket.sh:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='***'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='***'
REGION='us-east-1' 
aws s3 mb "s3://$1"
aws s3 cp "s3://frombucket/testfile.txt" "s3://$1/testfile.txt"
```

Comment: follow up question: I wrote the following 2 commands:
`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='***' AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='***' REGION='us-east-1' aws s3 mb "s3://$1"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='***' AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='***' aws s3 cp "s3://frombucket/testfile.txt" "s3://$1/testfile.txt"`

the second command is to copy file from one bucket to another and it fails giving the same error. It fails to even create a bucket. Both lines work when used individaully but not in a bash file. I also tried everything on separate lines but did not work. Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: Create a script with the line `ps -ef | grep $$ | grep -v grep` and run it.  Does the output cointain: `bash ./scriptname.sh` or `sh ./scriptname.sh` or something else?  Also, what does your command line environment output when you enter `echo $0`?

I'm wondering if you're using the same shell in your command line environment that you are in your script.  If the above two steps don't both say `bash` somewhere then that may be related to your problem.

Comment: Also, try replacing `aws s3 mb` with `echo` and see if the string that it prints out is mangled in some way.  I don't think this has anything to do with the `aws` utility--something is amiss with how your shell is handling the parameter.

Comment: `ubuntu    7095  7079  0 22:19 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
ubuntu    7096  7095  0 22:19 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -ef`
This is the output from `ps -ef | grep $$ | grep -v grep` It outputs `-bash` when I enter `echo $0`.  When my replace aws s3 mb with echo everything works fine and output of file name is as I enter it. I really appreciate your help with this. I will keep trying something. If anything occurs in your mind that I might be missing please do let me know. :-)